# Font Awesome add multiple icons to button

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have this button:

```
<button type="button" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-default btn-gray btn-primary btn-primary2 btn-success2 btn-warning btn-black btn-success btn_bottom_padding" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-bind="css: {'btn-gray': IsGray(), 'btn-danger': IsRed(),'btn-success':IsGreen(), 'btn-primary': IsBlue(),'btn-success2':IsLimegreen(), 'btn-primary2': IsSkyblue(),'btn-warning':IsOrange(),'btn-black': IsBlack(),'btn-default':IsWhite()},click:$root.GetClick">
   <span data-bind="text:ShortName()"></span>
   <span data-bind="visible: IsRed()" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span>
   @*<span data-bind="" class="fa fa-bolt"></span>*@
</button>
```

The thing is I wanted to add multiple icons to it like:

[image]

I only managed to add the exclamation triangle icon, but if I tried to add another one neither the first one would not appear. Is there any way that I can add all those four icons like in the attached button image?

Comment: Can you get a working fiddle for us to play with?

Comment: you'd need to have a single image containing everything you need, or use a div instead of a button and include multiple div/span elements for each icon you need shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add them in separate spans: [Example](http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/gPGRpa?editors=110)

```
<span class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span>
<span class="fa fa-bar-chart"></span>
<br>
<span class="fa fa-bolt"></span>
<span class="fa fa-ban"></span>
```